# Will protobuf generate bitwise perfect copy if ran on the same input on different languages/architectures?

Tags: cross-platform, protocol-buffers

If I use the same `.proto` file, across several machine (arm, x86, amd64 etc.) with implementations written in different languages (c++, python, java, etc.), will the same message result in the exact same byte sequence when serialized across those different configurations?

I would like to use these bytes for hashing to ensure that the same message, when generated on a different platform, would end up with the exact same hash.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208725/is-protocol-buffer-serialization-output-fully-deterministic

Comment: Thanks! deterministic was the term I couldn't come up with while searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Often, but not quite always"

The reasons you might get variance include:

- it is only a "should", not a "must" that fields are written in numerical sequential order - [citation, emphasis mine](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding):

  > when a message is serialized its known fields **should** be written sequentially by field number

  and it is not *demanded* that fields are thus ordered (it is a "must" that deserializers be able to handle out-of-order fields); this can apply especially when discussing unexpected/extension fields; if two serializations choose different field orders, the bytes will be different
- protobuf can be constructed by merging two partial messages, which will by necessity cause out-of-order fields, but when re-serializing an object deserialized from a merged message, it may become normalized (sequential)
- the "varint" encoding allows some small subtle ambiguity... the number `1` would usually be encoded as 0x01, but it could *also* be encoded as 0x8100 or 0x818000 or 0x81808080808000 - the specification doesn't actually *demand* (AFAIK) that the shortest version be used; I am not aware of any implementation that actually outputs this kind of subnormal form, though :)
- some options are designed to be forward- and backward- compatible; in particular, the `[packed=true]` option on `repeated` primitive values can be safely toggled at any time, and libraries are expected to cope with it; if you *originally* serialized it in one way, and *now* you're serializing it with the other option: the result can be different; a side-effect of this is that a specific library could also simply *choose* to use the alternate representation, especially if it knows it will be smaller; if two libraries make different decisions here - different bytes

In most common cases, yes: it'll be reliable and repeatable. But this is not an actual guarantee.

The bytes should be *compatible*, though - it'll still have the same *semantics* - just not the same bytes. It shouldn't matter what language, framework, library, runtime, or processor you use. If it does: that's a bug.