# Is the string/bytestring resulting from protobuf serialization of the same record value always the same?

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I have some record value and I protobuf-serialize it multiple times, will I always get back the same bytestring?

Conversely, if I have two properly-serialized strings for the same protobuf type and the strings have different values and I deserialize them, is it possible to get back the same record value?

Comment: Additional duplicate for more context: [Is protocol buffer serialization output fully deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31208725/is-protocol-buffer-serialization-output-fully-deterministic) - basically, the answer is "technically no, but it often will be the same"

Comment: As a slight note: your "conversely" is true even if the bytes are not the same; the same data can *in theory* be serialized into multiple different byte sequences, but it should still deserialize back to the same message data. To illustrate with a non-protobuf example: `{"a":1,"b":2}` is *semantically* the same as `{"b":2,"a":1}`, and will deserialize back into the same message data, despite being different actual payloads - the exact same thing is possible in protobuf